# In this AutohotKeys code, how to have each text-line of each list in its own line, instead of having all of them together in the same single line

Tags: autohotkey

I have this Autohotkeys code to randomly choose one line of text from each of the three lists of text-lines within the same file, and copy them together to the clipboard.
It works perfectly fine, but *it is not practical to add new lines of long text* to the code.
So I wonder if it is possible editing it **to have each text-line in its own separated line in the code**, instead of having all text-lines of each list in one single line, as it is right now.
For instance instead of having each list like this:

> list = 1st text-line,2nd text-line,3rd text-line,4th text-line

better have them similar to something like this:

> list = 
> 1st text-line,
> 2nd text-line,
> 3rd text-line,
> 4th text-line

I've tried several options I know, but all I get are blank lines.
This is my current code:

```
Random, rand1, 1, 4
Random, rand2, 1, 4
Random, rand3, 1, 4

; Definining 3 lists of text lines:
list1 = 1st text-line,2nd text-line,3rd text-line,4th text-line
list2 = 5th text-line,6th text-line,7th text-line,8th text-line
list3 = 9th text-line,10th text-line,11th text-line,12th text-line

; Selecting randomly one text-line from each list:
selectedLine1 := strsplit(list1,",")[rand1]
selectedLine2 := strsplit(list2,",")[rand2]
selectedLine3 := strsplit(list3,",")[rand3]

; Concatenating the 3 selected text-lines and copy them to the clipboard:
clipboard = %selectedLine1%`n%selectedLine2%`n%selectedLine3%

; Seeing the result on a message box:
msgbox, Randoms: %rand1%, %rand2%, %rand3%`nSelected lines:`n%selectedLine1%`n%selectedLine2%`n%selectedLine3%
```

My AutoHotkey is version 1.1.36.02 . Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
Random, rand1, 1, 4
Random, rand2, 1, 4
Random, rand3, 1, 4

; Definining 3 lists of text lines:
list1 =
(
1st text-line
2nd text-line
3rd text-line
4th text-line
)
list2 =
(
5th text-line
6th text-line
7th text-line
8th text-line
)
list3 =
(
9th text-line
10th text-line
11th text-line
12th text-line
)

; Selecting randomly one text-line from each list:
selectedLine1 := strsplit(list1,"`n")[rand1]
selectedLine2 := strsplit(list2,"`n")[rand2]
selectedLine3 := strsplit(list3,"`n")[rand3]

; Concatenating the 3 selected text-lines and copy them to the clipboard:
clipboard = %selectedLine1%`n%selectedLine2%`n%selectedLine3%

; Seeing the result on a message box:
msgbox, Randoms: %rand1%, %rand2%, %rand3%`nSelected lines:`n%selectedLine1%`n%selectedLine2%`n%selectedLine3%
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).